# Specific array type from UML?

Tags: java, uml

I was wondering if this UML specifies that it HAS to be an ordinary array in the constructor of the Lesson class. I'm wondering because it doesn't include any size, and it has a relationship with another class from 0..*.

Not sure if I'm reading the UML correctly if I decide to make it an ArrayList -  or would that be allowed?

[image: UML Screenshot here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML doesn't mandate anything about how the relationship is implemented when it comes to concrete code. It just specifies that a lesson has 0 to many associated Files (with a steer that the relationship is named resources).

As such, you can use any kind of collection (UML doesn't tell you if there is any ordering so it could be an Array, List, Set etc, whatever makes sense to your program.

The fact it is 0..* additionally means that no files is a valid state and so you can choose whether to populate the collection in a constructor or to construct it empty then add resources.

Comment: Oh okay, does that count for UML as a whole? ie. if it gave more sense to use double instead of an int, in some fictional scenario?

Comment: You are now asking about the type which is either decrlared in the property or as role in an association. In any case such a change is a model change. You can do that but it will have consequences.

Comment: Yes, agree, and to be honest there is a wider question of who created the UML and who is writing the code and what the mutual expectations are between the two. The designer will probably not be considering the low level details the coder will face and so may define some details that don't really work so well in the code. Ideally there'd be a bit of conversation about any departures from the design. Personally I create UML diagrams and write code but tend to keep both fluid as things evolve.

Comment: Traditionally software development often had a long design phase when details were expected to be closely defined. In some situations that approach is appropriate, but more often I find design artefacts are less prescriptive, more of a high level steer with more autonomy expected in coding (roughly speaking waterfall Vs agile, though this approach to design is just a very small aspect of what you might mean by agile software development)

Comment: The media break between design and code is still a big one. Many questions here make it clear than UML isn't tought the right way. People try coding graphically which is just a waste of time. Designing in UML is really nice. But hopping of the boat and pass meaningful parts to the coders is not that easy. That's where many projects fail and frustration on both sides is pre-programmed.